# A morphism of principal $G$ bundles over the base space $B$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $p_1:E_1\to B$ and  $p_2:E_2\to B$ be two principal $G$-bundles.
Let $f:E_1\to E_2$ be a principal $G$-bundle morphism. I want to show that $f$ is an isomorphism. I read somewhere that it is enough to show that it is bijective on the fibers. Let $x\in B$ and consider the restriction $f:p_1^{-1}(x)\to  p_2^{-1}(x)$ the map is well defined since $p_2\circ f=p_1$. I want to show that this restriction is bijective.

**injectivity:**

Suppose $f(e_1)=f(e_1')$. Since the action of $G$ is transitive on the fibers, there exists $g\in G$ such that $e_1'=ge_1$ hence $f(e_1)=f(ge_1)$ but the map $f$ is by definition $G$-equivariant so $f(ge_1)=gf(e_1)$ now the action is being free then $g=1$ hence $e_1=e_1'$.

As for surjectivity I think it follwos from transitivity of the action but I can't see how to prove it. And finally I want to know how to go from bijection on the fibers $p_1^{-1}(x)\to  p_2^{-1}(x)$ to the bijection on the hole spaces $E_1\to E_2$. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y \in p_2^{-1}(x)$, we want to find some $y' \in p_1^{-1}(x)$ such that $f(y') = y$. Let $z \in p_1^{-1}(x)$ be any element<sup>*</sup>, then $f(z) \in p_2^{-1}(x)$; since $G$ acts transitively on fibers, there exists $g \in G$ such that $g \cdot f(z) = y$. But $g \cdot f(z) = f(g \cdot z) = y$, so we can just set $y' = g \cdot z$.

So now we know that $f$ is a ($G$-equivariant) bijection on each fiber. To construct an inverse of $f$, let $y \in E_2$, $p_2(y) = x$; then $f_x : p_1^{-1}(x) \to p_2^{-1}(x)$ is a bijection, so set $g(y) = f_x^{-1}(y)$. This gives a map $g : E_2 \to E_1$, and it is clear by definition that $g$ is an inverse of $f$. The question is whether $g$ is a bundle map.

Since $f$ is $G$-equivariant, it's easy to see that $g$ is too: $f(h \cdot y) = h \cdot f(y) \implies h \cdot y = g(h \cdot f(y))$ (and $f$ is surjective). It also satisfies $p_1 \circ g = p_2$ (because $p_2 \circ f = p_1$). It remains to show that it is continuous. Let $V \subset E_1$ be an open set; WLOG $p_1(V) = U$ is a trivializing open set (you should check that $p_1$ is an open map, it's an insightful exercise; basically, the standard projection $U \times G \to U$ is open), so that $V \cong U \times G$. But then by definition of $G$, $g^{-1}(V) = p_2^{-1}(U) \cong U \times G$ too, which is open, so $g$ is continuous.

---

I am assuming the projection maps of the principal bundles are surjective. In general the result is not true otherwise: $\emptyset \to B$ is a principal $G$-bundle, and there is a morphism $\emptyset \to E$ for any other principal bundle, but it need not be an isomorphism...

Comment: I do not understand your last paragraph "I am assuming the projection maps of the principal bundles are surjective. In general the result is not true otherwise: $\emptyset \to B$ is a principal $G$-bundle, and there is a morphism $\emptyset \to E$ for any other principal bundle, but it need not be an isomorphism..." Is your $E$ equal to $B$? I am sorry, can you explain what you mean

Comment: It is also not clear how trivialization is playing any role here... Given $f:E_1\rightarrow E_2$ you constructed $g:E_2\rightarrow E_1$... This $g$ is such that $p_1\circ g=p_2$... You want to prove this $g$ is continuous, you took an open set $V\subseteq E_1$ and trying to prove that $g^{-1}(V)$ is open... please explain why trvialization is coming in puncture..

Comment: All I could see is...  As $p_1\circ g=p_2$, we have $(p_1\circ g)^{-1}(U)=p_2^{-1}(U)$ for every open $U$ in $M$.. This means $g^{-1}(p_1^{-1}(U))=(p_1\circ g)^{-1}(U)=p_2^{-1}(U)$ is open as $p_2$ is continuous/smooth... Thus, I can prove that for open sets $V$ of the form $p_1^{-1}(U)$ for some open $U$ we have $g^{-1}(V)$ is open... i.e., $g^{-1}(V)$ is open if $V=p_1^{-1}(U)$ for some open $U$.. I could not see how this generalized for an arbitrary open set...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Let $E_1 = \varnothing$ and $E_2$ be any other principal bundle. You always have a morphism $E_1 \to E_2$, but it's not an isomorphism in general. As for the continuity, this is basic point-set topology. Any open set $V$ of $E_1$ is the union of trivializing open subsets. If the preimage of all these trivializing open subsets is open, then the preimage of $V$ is open too.

Comment: oh.. I read it wrong. My mistake... About continuity I do not see why  trivializing is coming here..  I think I am not understanding the English, it is not my native language so having some difficulty...  Apologies for asking more questions but I am not able to understand the point..